# Dismissing LoginVC after successful login

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

In my app the user is directed to a sign up/ log in viewController if they are not signed in. This logic happens in `SceneDelegate`, I am stuck on trying to present the initial view controller after the user either signs up or logs in. I've tried dismissing the view controller and presenting the root view controller, but neither has worked. Here is the logic in `SceneDelegate` after their logged in status is checked:

```
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = OnboardingVC()
```

After logging in/creating account this is an example of what I've tried after successful login or account creation, but doesn't work:

```
if let vc = self.onboardingVC?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "JournalVC") as? JournalVC {
     self.onboardingVC?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and

```
self.onboardingVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I've looked through some examples, but they all involve `AppDelegate`, which I am not using, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, just for the sake of example, that your way of implementing this in the app delegate was:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {
            let ud = UserDefaults.standard
            if ud.string(forKey: "username") != nil {
                print("app delegate: user has logged in")
                let vc = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userHasLoggedIn")
                self.window!.rootViewController = vc
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Then the exactly parallel way to do it in the scene delegate would be:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {
            let ud = UserDefaults.standard
            if ud.string(forKey: "username") != nil {
                print("scene delegate: user has logged in")
                let vc = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userHasLoggedIn")
                self.window!.rootViewController = vc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Taken from my https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample )

Comment: Yes I understand that logic, but my question is what to do immediately after a user signs up. How do I get rid of the login VC/ present the rootVC from that loginVC

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a function in your scene delegate to present the view controller post successful login

In your scene delegate write a function

```
func launchJourneyViewController() {
    let journeyViewController = JourneyViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = journeyViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible() 
}
```

In your login view controller after successful login , you can write a function

```
func onLoginSuccess() {
  let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
    if let sceneDelegate : SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate) {   
      sceneDelegate.launchJourneyViewController()
     }
}
```

This considers the fact that you have only one scene in your application